# my cat has really bad diarea and it smells really bad and she's lost a lot of weight

Tags: health

I can't afford the local vet, want $100 just to look at her, and the worm meds I have given her haven't helped,she's gotten so skinny and she leaks now, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remember that worming medications are a mild poison. Don't give them to an animal that is already ill unless you are __sure__ that's the cause of the illness. If you don't want to lose the cat, the vet visit is worth the cost; if you really can't afford it try contacting the local spca and see whether they have any pet-care assistance program you might qualify for. This is a life-threatening condition if the cat is losing weight

Comment: Ty, I will try the SPCA.

Answer (score 4):

Diarrhea is a serious and, potentially, fatal illness with many potential causes. So, it's not so easy to just help in this respect, you're really are best to see a vet.

The biggest risk is fluid loss, so you need to keep your cat hydrated. So, remove any foods and put them away for at least 12 hours to help settle the guts down, but make plenty of clean, fresh, water available (in multiple bowls) to help her replenish water loss. You can also mix the water (50/50) with gatorade to provide some minerals back into the system that may be lost from the diarrhea.

Now, I realize that vets can be expensive, try to contact them to see if you can work out a payment plan if needed. Many are compassionate to animals and will help in that way, so that gets you past the immediate cost hurdle. You need to do this, because, if you see any of the following ***then you must get her to a vet immediately***:

- Issue persists for 24 hours
- Cat appears lethargic or very weak
- Cat vomits
- Cat seems to have a fever

You should also ask the vet for some home care advice as well. I have to really stress, though, that unless the episode passes quickly, the risk to her increases the longer that she doesn't see a vet. So, really, try to negotiate a way to pay in instalments if you can.